# list on range with kind of repeat the list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Here is my code, everything works fine except def advance(stringlist)

```
def printList(stringlist):
    print stringlist or []
def add (stringlist, string):
    item = [] if string is None else [string]
    return item + (stringlist or [])
def current (stringlist):
    item =''
    return item + stringlist[0]
def advance(stringlist):
    item = []
    item2 = item + stringlist[1:]
    for item in range(5):
        return item2
```

and Im looking for the result of this

```
>>> myList = None
>>> printList(myList)
[]
>>> for word in ['laundry','homework','cooking','cleaning']:
...     myList = add(myList, word)
...     printList(myList)
... 
[laundry]
[homework, laundry]
[cooking, homework, laundry]
[cleaning, cooking, homework, laundry]
>>> current(myList)
'cleaning'
>>> for i in range(5):
...     myList = advance(myList)
...     printList(myList)
...     print current(myList)
... 
[cooking, homework, laundry, cleaning]
cooking
[homework, laundry, cleaning, cooking]
homework
[laundry, cleaning, cooking, homework]
laundry
[cleaning, cooking, homework, laundry]
cleaning
[cooking
```

but I'm getting

```
['cooking', 'homework', 'laundry']
cooking
['homework', 'laundry']
homework
['laundry']
laundry
[]
```

other codes works fine, just only on the 'advance' code
how can I make the list become four words and not deleting any string from it?

Comment: Why do you return `'' + stringlist[0]` for the `current()` function? *Just* `stringlist[0]` would suffice just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a list *rotation*; this is easiest accomplished with some list slices:

```
def advance(stringlist):
    return stringlist[1:] + stringlist[:1]
```

This takes the first element of the list and places it at the end of a new list:

```
>>> def advance(stringlist):
...     return stringlist[1:] + stringlist[:1]
... 
>>> advance(['cooking', 'homework', 'laundry', 'cleaning'])
['homework', 'laundry', 'cleaning', 'cooking']
```

Your version simply returned *just* `stringlist[1:]` (so everything but the first element); a `return` statement ends the function there and then, it does not return multiple times when placed in a loop.